# Recyclerview with searchview unbinding problem

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a filter of date search for my recyclerview, my performFiltering log gives me the correct set of records, the count of the records shown by recyclerview is correct, but the data is incorrect, i know this is because recyclerview recycles views but even after hours i couldnt find a way to unbind the data so that the accurate filtered results are shown. Help!

```
    package com.emlocks.timeaccess;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static com.emlocks.timeaccess.R.layout.list_item1;

public class NotificationList extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences prefs;


    private Gson gson;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;


    List<Map<String, String>> notifList;
    List<Map<String, String>> notifListFull;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.prefs), MODE_PRIVATE);

        gson = new Gson();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.notificationsRecycler);


        prefs = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.prefs), MODE_PRIVATE);

        notifList = gson.fromJson(prefs.getString("notifs", ""), new TypeToken<List<Map<String, String>>>() {
        }.getType());
        notifListFull = new ArrayList<>(notifList);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(NotificationList.this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new NotificationListAdapter());


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu);

        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dilog = new DatePickerDialog(
                        NotificationList.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                                String monthText ;
                                String dayText;
                                month = month + 1;
                                if(month < 10){
                                    monthText = "0" + month;
                                } else{
                                    monthText = String.valueOf(month);
                                }
                                if(dayOfMonth<10){
                                    dayText = "0" + dayOfMonth;
                                } else{
                                    dayText = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                                }
                                String date = dayText + "/" + monthText + "/" + year;
                                searchView.setQuery(date, true);
                            }
                        }, year, month, day
                );
                dilog.show();

            }
        });

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                new NotificationListAdapter().getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }


    class NotificationListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationList.NotificationListAdapter.VH> implements Filterable {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public NotificationListAdapter.VH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
            View listItem1 = layoutInflater.inflate(list_item1, viewGroup, false);
            NotificationList.NotificationListAdapter.VH viewHolder = new NotificationList.NotificationListAdapter.VH(listItem1);
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NotificationList.NotificationListAdapter.VH vh, int i) {
            Map<String, String> o = notifList.get(i);
            Log.d("TAG", "perform " + notifList.get(i).get("title"));
            vh.tv1.setText(o.get("title"));
            vh.tv2.setText(o.get("body"));

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return notifList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return notifFilter;
        }

        private Filter notifFilter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                List<Map<String, String>> filteredList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    filteredList.addAll(notifListFull);
                } else {
                    String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                    for (Map<String, String> item : notifList) {
                        if (item.get("title").toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                            filteredList.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                results.values = filteredList;
                Log.d("TAG", "performFiltering: " + results.values);
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                notifList.clear();
                notifList.addAll((List<Map<String, String>>) results.values);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        public class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView tv1, tv2;

            public VH(View listItem1) {
                super(listItem1);
                this.tv1 = listItem1.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                this.tv2 = listItem1.findViewById(R.id.tvbody);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making a new  `NotificationListAdapter` each time in `onQueryTextChange` instead of using the RecyclerView's adapter.

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    recyclerView.getAdapter().getFilter().filter(newText);
    return false;
}
```